# Is it possible to access binary image data in GLKTextureInfo?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit

Is raw image data available in GLKTextureInfo or in some related object?

Is it possible to create textures in GLKit basing on such raw-data image buffers? Like in non-ES OpenGL, using the glTexImage2D()?

Comment: Maybe migrate to Game Development?

Answer (score -1):

There isn't any need to do so.  `GLKTextureLoader's` purpose is to remove boilerplate from creating textures from various image file formats.  If you already have the decoded raw binary data, then you can just call `glGenTextures`/`glTexImage2D` as usual: there isn't anything left that GLKit can really do to help you.

Comment: I have a font in form of image. Loading means splitting it into letters.